# Idiomatic way to draw a curve over a bar series chart

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, data-visualization, wpftoolkit, datavisualization.toolkit

What I have is a `BarSeries` to display a histogram (rotated by 90 degrees, compared to the common way to draw histograms).

Putting aside the question if that's the best way to go about drawing a histogram, using the classes in `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization` (although comments are welcome), **what would be the best way to draw a curve over such a chart**?

This curve (just a dotted line gaussian in my case) must be probably scaled and positioned inside the "coordinate system" of the chart. (The scare quotes are intended to indicate that with a bar series chart, there isn't a actual two-dimensional coordinate system, but adjusting bar dimensions and gaps I think it could effectively be turned into one.)

I've done a bit of research and started played around a bit with `AdornerDecorator`s providing me with a `AdornerLayer` to draw on, but there are also `StackedPanel`s and potentially other options, so if anyone knows of a good way to implement what I need, that'd probably save me a lot of trial-and-error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add both a `ColumnSeries` as well as a `LineSeries` inside the same `Chart` element. The following snippet also contains the `LayoutTransform` which rotates the whole thing.

```
<Grid>
  <Chart>
    <Chart.LayoutTransform>
      <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="90"/>
    </Chart.LayoutTransform>

    <ColumnSeries></ColumnSeries>
    <LineSeries></LineSeries>
  </Chart>
</Grid>
```